# Run github action on pushing paths but not on merge from master

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github action that builds some assets, which should only run once when specific paths are changed. So the Github action looks like this:

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'some/path/**'
```

This works fine most of the time. The problems start when I merge a branch that had this action run (so `some/path/...` changes) to master. From then on, merging master into any branch that does not have such changes triggers the action for that branch - which I don't want.

How would you deal with this, if you wanted specific changes to specific paths to only trigger the action once? Any way to add like a merge from master exclusion? A different strategy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple checks e.g. if you want it to run only on main branch and this path, you can have

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'some/path/**'
```

This will trigger only when there is a push on that path on `main` branch

Comment: My problem is that I want it to run on all branches, but not run when I push a merge from master TO those branches, with master containing the path changes, but not the branch itself.